# Using STUFF in order to get multiple elements into one block in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I have three tables.

1st Table is called Customers with this dummy info in it:

[image]

2nd table is called Customer_Product with this dummy info in it:

[image]

3rd table is called Products with this dummy info in it:

[image]

And the diagram looks like this:

[image]

I currently have this code that I wrote:

```
SELECT 
    A.Customer_Name [Customer Name], 
    (SELECT CASE
        WHEN A.Customer_ID = A.Customer_Parent_ID
            THEN 'Is the Parent'
        ELSE(
        SELECT F.Customer_Name 
        FROM dbo.Customers F 
        Where F.Customer_ID = A.Customer_Parent_ID)
     END)  [Customer Parent's Name],
    C.Product_Name [Product They Own]
FROM dbo.Customers A 
JOIN Customer_Product B ON A.Customer_ID = B.Customer_ID
JOIN Products C ON C.Product_ID = B.Product_ID
```

That gives this output:

[image]

My question is how can I write a query that instead of what its currently giving me, it would give me an output that looks like this:

[image]

Thank you for any and all help! I'm new to SQL so an answer here doesn't really stand out to me, that current code is the closest I can seem to get to what I want. I realize I'll need to use STUFF, but I don't understand how. I've been taking a look at this post ([how to get name from another table with matching id in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193986/how-to-get-name-from-another-table-with-matching-id-in-another-table)) and trying to use it to work for me, but with little luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the script you have a CTE.  Then, once you define it as a CTE, you can run this.

```
SELECT Customer_name,
      STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + [Product They Own] 
        FROM CTE
        WHERE Customer_name= final.Customer_name
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS [Products They Own] 
FROM CTE final
GROUP BY Customer_name
```

Comment: Thank you so much!